# PIC - Accessing udata through pointer in another file

Tags: pic, c, pointers

So I have a list of clockings in my udata in, let's say, `clock.c`.
I have read that udata has to be accessed through a pointer, well okay, fair enough.

Above `defines.h`

```
//Warning! This has to be conform the linkerscript, you can not just increase it.
#define CLOCKINGLISTLENGTH 50
#define KEYLENGTH 6

//A clocking consists out of a key, time and in/out (and status)
//All the clockings together are the "clockings" list.
//These clockings will await to be transmitted.
typedef struct
{
    unsigned isActive:1;
    unsigned needsTransmit:1;
    unsigned inOut:1;
    unsigned val1:1;
    unsigned val2:1;
    unsigned val3:1;
    unsigned val4:1;
    unsigned val5:1;
} byte;

typedef struct
{
    byte bits;
    unsigned char key[KEYLENGTH];
    unsigned char time[6];
} Clocking;
```

Above `clock.c` file.

```
#include "defines.h"
#pragma udata large_udata
Clocking clocking_queue[CLOCKINGLISTLENGTH];
#pragma udata
Clocking *clockings = clocking_queue;//Access udata through pointer!
```

In `eeprom.c` file.

```
#include "defines.h"
extern Clocking *clockings;

void writeClockingToEEPROM(char clockingIndex){
 int eepromIndex = 0;
 Write_b_eep(eepromIndex,clockings[clockingIndex].key[0]);
}
```

So my question is: "How to access udata from another file through a pointer".
I simply want to use my clockings_queue (which should be accessed through *clockings pointer) in my EEPROM.c, so that I can store clockings in EEPROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know where `clockings` is in `eeprom.c`.  There's nothing to tell the compiler that `clockings` is in `clock.c`.

In order to fix this, move `extern Clocking *clocking;` from `eeprom.c` into `defines.h`.  This way, `clock.c` and `eeprom.c` know that `clockings` exists.  The declaration of `clockings` should be in the header.  The definition should be in `clock.c` (as it currently is).

Here's a link for an explanation on `extern`: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/

Comment: Both include `defines.h`. Is it safe to forward-declare `Clocking *clocking` as an `extern` variable? Even when I declare it later on as a regular variable (in `clock.c`)?

Comment: @FauZe Make sure the contents of the header are wrapped with an `#ifndef [Some Name]` `#define [Some Name]` `#endif`. Or place a `#pragma once` statement at the top of the file.  This will tell the compiler to use the file only once during compilation.  I think the Microchip compilers support `#pragma once`. In order to use `clockings` in multiple c files, it needs to be forward declared in a header file.  That way, the compiler knows about the variable.